# I want to access DSpace search input field text through XSLT

Tags: xslt, dspace

I want to replace Persian numbers to English when user enters a query.

My question is how to access text of the query that users enter through XSLT ?

Any better methods to achieve this goal ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZpmO.png)

Comment: Please provide an example input (as code, not picture) and the expected output - see: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you are trying to access the query value within DSpace XMLUI.

If I run the a query for "thesis" on the DSpace demo server:

http://demo.dspace.org/xmlui/discover?scope=%2F&query=thesis&submit=

You can view the source XML with the following URL

http://demo.dspace.org/xmlui/discover?scope=%2F&query=thesis&submit=&XML

You can see that the search term is available with the following XPATH

```
//dri:div[@n='discovery-search-box']//dri:field[@n='query']/dri:value/text()
```

Comment: actually i want to change the value with other characters,does it work for this mean?

Comment: I stumbled upon this question and answer while looking for something unrelated. Adding `&XML` to one of my scrappers helped tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

If [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals#Usage) is correct, it is merely a matter of replacing each Persian digit with its Arabic equivalent:

```
<xsl:variable name="input">۴۰۲۷</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="translate($input, '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹', '0123456789')"/>
```

returns:

```
4027
```

Comment: Thank you,but unfortunately it doesn't work for this problem

Comment: Then edit your question and clarify what "this problem" is - as you were already asked to do.